# Clarifying understanding of this conditional

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, conditional-statements

I currently am learning C# through a series of tutorials and was wondering if my understanding of this conditional makes sense.

[image]

What confused me about this code was that the tutorial said that if 1 was 0, then the validateNames bool would seem useless logically. I ended up finding out that validateNames indicates that the code should at some point validate not just one, but multiple names. I came to the conclusion that the bool would seem useless if players was set to 0, because you wouldn't need a bool indicating the code is going to run on multiple names when the second conditional will run the code when there is only 1 or more players. Does my conclusion make sense? I'm not completely confident about it.

[image]

Here's what the guy that made the tutorial said about the code if anyone needs more information about it to help answer my question.

Comment: I am really confused as to what you are confused about, the context of this code and what this guy is talking about

Comment: It is impossible to give guidance here without seeing a [mcve] so we can see what, for example, `validateNames` and `players` is. Additionally, it seems very odd to come to SO to ask 'what did this guy mean?' rather than asking him directly.

Comment: Why not ask “the guy”?   SO isn’t really for explaining someone else’s code

Comment: We can only guess and without context, we are guessing blind. Maybe this is code that should run if validatePalyers returns true? It is propably used as a single/primary check somewhere above that code. Honestly validateNames sounds like a function name, but that is definitely not a functiuon call. Questionable logic is not the only thing going wrong with the example code you showed. Terrible variable/property naming is propably too.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Why do you post image of code and image of text instead of posting actual code and text?

Comment: maybe he ment you could just flip them (that's what I would do) since I'ld guess the test `(isOnline && players > 1)` is less expensive than doing `validateNames` assuming all available player names are probably somehow compared to find douplicates(?) or as already mentioned compared to a database of "bad words" ;) if the first condition is `false` it won't even execute the second so always try to bring the cheapest one first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say if your understanding is correct, because its not clear from your question what your understanding of the code is.

When you say:

> I came to the conclusion that the bool would seem useless if players
>   was set to 0

Which bool are you referring to?

Regardless, as you're learning, I'd recommend getting into the habit of creating small programs to test logic like this.

You can use a tool like [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (which I find invaluable) or an online IDE like [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

Something like this will show you whats happening here, which should help clear things up:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        Console.Write("Test 1:");
        TestBoolLogic(true, true, 0);
        Console.Write("Test 2:");
        TestBoolLogic(true, true, 1);
        Console.Write("Test 3:");
        TestBoolLogic(true, true, 2);
        Console.Write("Test 4:");
        TestBoolLogic(false, true, 0);
        Console.Write("Test 5:");
        TestBoolLogic(false, true, 1);
        Console.Write("Test 6:");
        TestBoolLogic(false, true, 2);
    }

    public static void TestBoolLogic(bool validateNames, bool isOnline, int players){
        if(validateNames || (isOnline && players > 1)){
            Console.WriteLine("Validating names");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("No validation");
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
Test 1:Validating names
Test 2:Validating names
Test 3:Validating names
Test 4:No validation
Test 5:No validation
Test 6:Validating names
```

So you can see that if 'validateNames' is true, then it will do the validation regardless of 'isOnline' or the value of 'players'.

In fact, I believe the runtime won't even bother evaluating the second part of the `or` operator because its already found a `true` condition.

Comment: "In fact, I believe the runtime won't even bother evaluating the second part of the or operator because its already found a true condition." That is indeed true. The || and && are "short circuiting". If the first condition gives a unambigious result, then 2nd is never even tested. | and & do not have this limitation, wich can be sometimes nessesary.

Comment: That's true that's why I woul in general always try to have the `cheaper` conditions first. In this case I'ld assume that `(isOnline && players > 1)` is less expensive to execute than `validateNames` (again assuming that this might require a database or comparing all player names against each other?)